# media queries not working in my code

Tags: css, web, media-queries

I've gone through all the help links for my problem with no results.  I am 
trying to get my media queries working for IPHONE 6.

Nothing happens.

I have a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Here are my link rel statements

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)"      href="portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css" />  

<link href="cliff.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

here are my media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{
.calendar
{width:70%;}    
}
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414x) and (max-device-width: 425px) { iPhone6+ Styles }
{
.calendar
{width:85%;}
.content
{float:none; width:100%;}
.sidebar1 {
display:none;}
.header {display:none;}
.maincontent {text-align:left;}

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{
.calendar
{width:85%;}
.content
{float:none; width:100%;}
.sidebar1 {
display:none;}
.header {display:none;}
.maincontent {text-align:left;}

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 359px) and (max-device-width: 361px) { iPhone6+ Alt Styles }
{
.calendar
{width:85%;}
.content
{float:none; width:100%;}
.sidebar1 {
display:none;}
.header {display:none;}
.maincontent {text-align:left;}

}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 319px) and (max-device-width: 480px) { iPhone5 or less Styles }
{
.calendar
{width:85%;}
.content
{float:none; width:100%;}
.sidebar1 {
display:none;}
.header {display:none;}
    .maincontent {text-align:left;}

}
```

I've put the media queries in each css file.
I've tried various max-width and max-height values recommended in my searches.

Nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: If this is your CSS copies as-is then there are potentially some syntax errors. For example `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414x) and (max-device-width: 425px) { iPhone6+ Styles }
{` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't work because you are doing this completly wrong. Use @media queries in this way.

```
<style>

.test{
    background-color:#F00;
    height:200px;
    width:1200px;
}

@media (max-width: 1260px) {
    .test{
    background-color:#0C0;
    width:900px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .test{
    background-color:#FF0;
    width:500px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
    .test{
    background-color:#0CF;
    width:320px;
    }
}

</style>

<div class="test"></div>
```